# Возможно ли перехватить нажатие кнопок регулировки громкости средствами js?

Tags: javascript

Врем привет! Во время просмотра сайта, необходимо перехватить нажатие кнопок регулировки громкости на смартфонах с android и ios средствами javascript. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: В Javascript-те есть медиа события.
Полный список событий - [вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).
Ну и [volumechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/volumechange) думаю то, что вы ищете.

Answer (score 1):

`volumechange` является частью спецификации HTML5 и относится только к медиа-элементам HTML5 `<audio> и <video>`
Те это не системная громкость - а громкость внутри DOM елемента.

Если данное приложение написано на Cordova например - то там есть возможность получать доступ к системным событиям и оборудованию.

Если оно просто работает внутри `WebView` в Android то надо использовать код на Java и вызывать его через `JavascriptInterface`.
Например:
HTML внутри WebView

```
<input value="Click" onclick="javascript:alert(test.getGreeting());"/>
```

По нажатию вызовет метод в Java

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaInterface(), "test");

private class MyJavaInterface {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String getGreeting() {
         return "Hello JavaScript!";
    }
}
```

А в Android API уже можно получить доступ ко всему к чему позволяет операционная система